# Java Instant Datetime how to get the Datetime with timezone offset only? without the region information

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8, utc

I am using the Java `Instant` to get the current date-time information, but it returns to me the UTC Datetime with `Z` or with `[Europe/Berlin]`. How do I get the only `Datetime` information with timezone offset?

Following is the code I have:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.now();

        System.out.println("Current Time : " + instant);

        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
        System.out.println("LocalDateTime : " + localDateTime);

        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime1 = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
        System.out.println("ZonedDateTime1: " + zonedDateTime1);
    }
}
```

Following is the output I have:

```
Current Time : 2022-04-13T08:22:35.362644Z
LocalDateTime : 2022-04-13T10:22:35.362644
ZonedDateTime1: 2022-04-13T10:22:35.362644+02:00[Europe/Berlin]
```

My expected output is:

```
expected output: 2022-04-13T10:22:35.362644+02:00
```

How can I get my expected output `2022-04-13T10:22:35.362644+02:00` using `Instant`? I am aware that I can do the substring(), but I do not want to do that. I am looking for some direct approach to achieve this. Please provide some suggestion.

Also, I do not wish to pass the region information as the application can be accessed across various regions so do not wish to hardcode the region in code.

Comment: Why do you want to use `Instant` when that doesn't include any offset information? It seems to me that what you need is `OffsetDateTime`. (And if `ZonedDateTime` has all the *information* you need, but you need a different format, then use a `DateTimeFormatter` rather than expecting the *default* string representation to be exactly what you want.)

Comment: I agree with @JonSkeet in the understanding that an `OffsetDateTime` is what you appear to need. When right now I executed `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())` in German time zone, I got `2022-04-13T11:34:10.078283+02:00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you need `Instant`. The following code gives your desired output:

```java
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
    }
}
```

When I run the above code, I get the following output:

```
2022-04-13T12:25:31.1157466+03:00
```

My local time zone is three hours ahead of UTC.

Comment: It would make more sense to use `OffsetDateTime.now()` if only offset information is needed though.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel they both give the same output.

Comment: Sure, but my point is that if the OP is looking for offset only, they should use `OffsetDateTime`, not `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

> How do I get the only Datetime information with timezone offset?

```
OffsetDateTime
.now() 
.toString()
```

> 2022-04-13T22:47:58.123793+02:00

Or, state your desired/expected time zone explicitly rather than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone.

```
OffsetDateTime
.now(
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" )
) 
.toString()
```

## `OffsetDateTime`

You asked:

> How do I get the only Datetime information with timezone offset?

To represent a date with time-of-day as seen in an offset of some number of hours-minutes-seconds from the meridian of UTC, use the [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class.

Calling [`OffsetDateTime.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#now()) implicitly applies the offset of your JVM’s [current default time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault()).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now() ;  // Uses current offset.
```

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://OffsetDateTime%20odt%20=%20OffsetDateTime.now()%20;%20%20//%20Uses%20current%20offset.).

> 2022-04-13T20:47:58.059193Z

The `Z` on the end means an offset of zero from UTC, and is pronounced “Zulu”.

The IdeOne.com site happens to use a default time zone of UTC itself, a.k.a. “Zulu time”. So let’s specify a time zone to see a different offset in action.

```
OffsetDateTime odt2 = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) ) ;  // Use the offset currently in effect for this particular time zone.
```

> 2022-04-13T22:47:58.123793+02:00

## `ZonedDateTime`

Usually it is better to use a full time zone rather than a mere offset. A time zone is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region as decided by their politicians.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) ) ;
```

> 2022-04-13T22:47:58.126001+02:00[Europe/Berlin]

But occasionally we need to deal with an offset rather than a zone. Doing SQL work with a database is one important example, as the SQL standard was written only for offsets rather than time zones.

## `Instant`

You asked:

> How can I get my expected output 2022-04-13T10:22:35.362644+02:00 using Instant?

You cannot.

The [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the meridian of UTC. An `Instant` object by definition is always “in UTC”, that is, carries an offset of zero.

If you have an `Instant` in hand, you can adjust into a time zone or offset. Rather than assume you know the correct offset, I suggest going through a time zone to let *java.time* look up the offset in effect at the moment.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = myInstant.atZone( z ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime() ;
```

Tip: Be aware that politicians change the time zone rules, and therefore the offset, with surprising frequency and disturbingly little forewarning. Be sure to keep the [*tzdata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) up to date if any zone of interest to you is changing. You will find *tzdata* file in (a) your JVM, (b) your host operating system, and (c) perhaps in ancillary systems such as your database server.

## `LocalDateTime`

Never use `LocalDateTime` class when tracking a moment, a specific point on the timeline. This class purposely lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. An object of `LocalDateTime` carries *only* a date and a time-of-day, nothing more.

I cannot imagine any scenario where calling `LocalDateTime#now` or `LocalDateTime.ofInstant` would be the right thing to do. In doing so, you would be purposely discarding vital information (the time zone or offset).

Comment: when I use Instant.now() I got wrong date, 2 days diff from what it should be. what might causing this?

Comment: @etomun Post a Question with your exact code, example input, expected output, and actual results.